# Login through Instagram in android

Tags: android, authentication, instagram, integration

Before implementing it I'm studying it and researching information about it but I didn't find any helpful material so that i come here to you respectful guys who can me guide on it how can I perform login through Instagram. There is not any helpful tutorial about it like login through Facebook. Helps from you will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is not much valuable now, but as instagram grows and becomes irreplaceable, instagram login may have second priority, (first will be always google).

There is no known way from firebase free version  to login through instagram. Currently firebase supports only these many ways:
Email/Password, Phone, Google, Play Games, Game Center, Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, Yahoo, Microsoft, Apple, Anonymous.

You can use firebase Blaze plan for this, and you will not find much support on the internet for this. In this website you will not have to write server side code: Use Instagram Sign In with Firebase https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth

This also may help: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/instagram

Comment: so can't we use Instagram integration in our app?

Comment: Im sorry, it is possible. But you will have to purchase Blaze plan from firebase for this.